# wrong chemfig format

Tags: vertical-alignment, arrows, chemfig

I would like to obtain something like:

( - C(=O) - O -)

and

[image]

with `chemfig` package but `\arrow` do not works in the second case (an enormous and not centred arrow is placed) and in the first case the =o is not displayed and it is not centred with the wrapping text:

```
        \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
        \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
        \usepackage[italian,english]{babel}
        \usepackage{graphicx}
        \usepackage{amsmath}
        \usepackage{geometry}
        \usepackage{midpage}
        \usepackage{scrextend}
        \usepackage{setspace} 
    \usepackage{chemfig}
    
    
    
    
    
    \begin{document}
    
    
    
    
    (\chemfig[atom sep=20pt,bond offset=2pt]{- C{=O} - O-} )
    
    \chemfig[ compound sep = 20 pt]{\pi^{*} \arrow<- \pi}
    
    \end{document}
```

is there anyone who can help me? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this is what you need:

```
\documentclass[border=2mm,varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\begin{document}

\schemestart
 \chemfig[atom sep=20pt,bond offset=2pt]{-C([2]=O)-O-}
\schemestop

\vspace{1cm}

\schemestart
  \chemfig{\pi}
  \arrow(.mid east--.mid west){->}
  \chemfig{\pi^{*}}
\schemestop
\end{document}
```

With the above code the result is:

[image]

**EDIT:** Second try:

```
\documentclass[border=2mm,varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{chemfig}

\begin{document}
\centering
\schemestart
\chemfig[sep=20pt,bond offset=2pt]{{(}-C{(}=O{)}-O-{)}}
\schemestop

\vspace{1cm}

\schemestart
  \chemfig{\pi}
  \arrow(.mid east--.mid west){->}[0,0.65] % 0.65 is a factor for the lenght of the arrow
  \chemfig{\pi^{*}}
\schemestop
\end{document}
```

And, the new drawing is:
[image]

Comment: Unfortunately not, I need to put these configuration inside brackets inside a normal text, so C=O should be encapsulated near the carbon (C(C=O)) and the arrow should be the same size as in the figure

Answer (score 2):

I'm not convinced you need `chemfig` for this. `chemfig` is for sceletal formulas and chemical reaction schemes. (BTW: `chemfig`'s `\arrow` is only defined inside those schemes).

I would go with something like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemformula}
\begin{document}

$\pi\to\pi^*$ % no package required

\ch[math-space=0pt]{$\pi$ -> $\pi^*$}

\ch{-C(=O)-O-{}}

\end{document}
```

[image]